# Governor limit for concurrent long-running transactions

Tags: apex, governorlimits

In the [Governor limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm), there is the following limit:

> Number of synchronous concurrent transactions for long-running transactions that last longer than 5 seconds for each org.

If i create a custom Apex REST resource (e.g. using `@RestResource(urlMapping='/whatever/v1/*')` annotation), and inside this resource in the actions i run some heavy `SOQL` queries, and i have a few thousand users call this API all at once (they do it via a mobile app in the field), and it so happens that some requests take longer than 5 seconds, are those considered `long-running transactions`?

Does it mean other users will be `denied` (what it says on the same page)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The system will observe that there are too many requests over 5 seconds long and deny any further requests until the long-running ones complete. In that case, you'd need the client to retry.

Comment: So same limit does not apply to the standard `query` API, that has a different API limit on 25 requests with each taking more than 20 seconds? But it applies to Apex API?

Comment: @zaitsman Right. Long-running transactions count for things like Visualforce, REST API calls, Lightning controllers, etc.

Comment: @sfdcfox I know it applies to custom webservice hosted via apex, but does it also applies to triggers running in backend when using composite apis?